# How to count the total number of pages in my document when using setcounter{page}{1}?

Tags: page-numbering

How do I count the total number of pages when using `setcounter{page}{1}` and fix my table of contents?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    
    \section{AAA}
    \lipsum[1-10]
    
    \newpage
    \section{BBB}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \lipsum[3-10]
    \newpage
    \section{CCC}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \lipsum[3-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: How would your readers find the pages if the TOC says “page 6”, but there are two or more pages numbered 6 in the document? Or maybe none. And, in any case, the TOC number refers to no page actually numbered 6.

Answer (score 4):

You can use what is called the *absolute* page number for content in the ToC. The code below updates `\addcontentsline` to insert exactly that (provided by the `abspage` module of [`zref`](//ctan.org/pkg/zref)) with each ToC entry.

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage[abspage]{zref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\addcontentsline}% <cmd>
  {\thepage}% <search>
  {\number\numexpr\value{abspage}+1}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{AAA}
\lipsum[1-10]

\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\section{BBB}
\lipsum[3-10]

\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\section{CCC}
\lipsum[3-10]

\end{document}
```

Note the use of an expression when storing the absolute page number. Here's a reference to that calculation from the [`zref` documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/zref):

> For technical and historical reasons the counter itself is zero
> based: if you use it directly on the first page, e.g with `\arabic{abspage}` you will
> get 0 as value.

As an aside: If you're performing similar tasks for similar things, it's better to combine them into one using a tailored macro. For example,

```
\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}{%
  \clearpage
  \setcounter{page}{1}%
  \oldsection
}
```

would allow you to simplify your code to just use `\section{<title>}` to insert a new page, reset the page counter and then proceed as usual with the regular sectional macro.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you help me number the pages on the header continuously from 1 to the last page, (in case there is setcounter {page} {1})?

Comment: @JackNguyễn: Consider [this option/code](https://pastebin.com/qmZCVsr6). Note that every `\chapter` will be set using the `plain` page style, not `fancy`. So if you want the headers/footers to change for those pages, you need to redefine that style as well using `\fancypagestyle{plain}{<page style settings>}`.